# How can iptables both have (ACCEPT, all, anywhere, anywhere) and (DROP, all, anywhere, anywhere) in its INPUT chain?

Tags: linux, iptables

> How can `iptables` both have `(ACCEPT, all, anywhere, anywhere)` and `(DROP, all, anywhere, anywhere)` in its INPUT chain?

How is it meaningful for `iptables` to both have rules for `ACCEPT` and `DROP` all traffic in its `INPUT` chain with a default policy of `DROP`?

In this case, will traffic actually be accepted or dropped? I see that special rules exists for `ssh` and `http`, so they would naturally take precendece, because they are more specific?

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh ctstate ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http ctstate ESTABLISHED
```

**iptables-save:**

```
iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sun Jun 23 10:21:50 2019
*filter
:INPUT DROP [1665:309354]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [10:520]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 23 10:21:50 2019
```

Comment: Could you show `iptables-save` output?

Comment: I've added it :) Can you clarify?

Comment: The `iptables -L` ouput does not show all details. It is clear in the `iptables-save` output that only all traffic on the interface `lo` (loopback) is accepted.

Comment: To answer your question: default will be dropping, as long as not related to interface `lo` or matching any of the specific rules. In iptables the rules are matched by their order first, then the default policy applies.

Comment: @hargut, but why are all these "anywhere" lines shown by `iptables -L`?

Comment: They match to the lines in `iptables-save` in the same order. `anywhere` means that there is no source/destination ip specified in the rule, so the rule matches any source/destination ip.

Comment: Still, how does it make sense to have `(ACCEPT,all,anywhere,anywhere)` and `(DROP,all,anywhere,anywhere)` in the INPUT chain? Aren't these mutually exclusive?

Comment: No, they are not - as the first displayed rule only matches traffic on interface `lo`. Everything coming through another device is not matched by this rule, and therefore not accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note the small print in the addendum to the `-L` flag in [iptables](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) and use the `-v` option:

> **`-L`, `--list [chain]`**
>   List all rules in the selected chain. ... **The *exact* rules are suppressed until you use**
>
> ```
>  iptables -L -v
> ```

Personally I prefer dumping the complete rule-set with `iptables-save` to get a quick overview as `iptables -L` also only displays the ***filter*** table by default and you have to explicitly request for instance the nat table.

Very useful in discussing  iptables rules sets is to add line-numbers to your output and to print numeric ip-addresses and port numbers:  `[sudo] iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers`

---

Because `ip-tables -L` doesn't display the exact rules and omits the interface the rule to trust all traffic on the loopback interface created with `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`  gets displayed as:

```
# iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

rather than:

```
# iptables -L -v -n --line-number

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1    75890 6101K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Also note how when the rule was created with `iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` without any restrictions on ip-address (ranges) with a either `-s ip-address[/netmask]`  and/or `-d ip-address[/netmask]` the rule applies to any source and destination ip-address (the 0.0.0.0/0 network/netmask).

---

Now although that was not exactly the case to answer to your original question:

> How can iptables have completely contrary rules in the same chain?

Because neither the kernel nor the iptables command to manipulate the rules interpret the rule set as a whole.

**Each packet is checked sequentially against the rules in the order they are listed in each relevant chain**.  On the first rule that is a dispositive match that processing stops.

That means that you as an administrator can easily create rules (in an incorrect order) that appear completely contrary but will never become applicable, as a packet will always to an earlier rule.

The kernel will happily accept:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 10.2.3.4/32 -d 10.3.4.5/32 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 2 -s 10.2.3.4/32 -d 10.3.4.5/32 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 3 -s 10.2.3.4/32 -d 10.3.4.5/32 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 4 -s 10.2.3.4/32 -d 10.3.4.5/32 -j DROP
```

(where the last three are completely irrelevant.) or something less contrived such as:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22  -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 2  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -s 10.1.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

You can have a rule "accept all SSH connections"  followed by a rule "don't except SSH connections from 10.1.0.0/16". Unfortunately that second rule, while perfectly valid, will never work, as SSH connections from a host with ip-address 10.1.2.3 will always first match on the  "accept all SSH connections"  rule.
Once you switch the order of those rules... Then things work as expected:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -s 10.1.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 2  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22  -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Nice answer. Very detailed and helpful. Thank you @HBrujin.

Answer (score 2):

The first line of `iptables -L`

`target prot opt source destination
ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere`

corresponds to the first rule of the `iptables-save` output:

`-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`

This rule only matches traffic coming from the interface `lo`, the loopback interface. It does not match any traffic coming from another interface (e.g. eth0).

Therefore the default policy `DROP` will affect any traffic from any device except `lo` as long as not matched and accepted by a specific rule (e.g. http, ssh, related-established, ...).

Unfortunately `iptables -L` output does not list/display the interface details. This can be clarified looking at `iptables-save` output, or using `iptables -L -v`.

Comment: But how do I see for each `iptables -L` rule what interface it affects? Nowhere, is the interface mentioned in the output. Can I make `iptables` display more verbosely the corresponding interface?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. For more iptables options/details please refere to `man iptables`.